# How to get values from filtered range object in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Spark 2.3.1 with Python 3.7.0 pre-packaged with the Spark distribution. I am applying a filter function on a Range object but I am getting a Filter object instead of an RDD collection of values.

How should I get the values from the Filter object?

```
>>> l = range(1,100)
>>> f = filter(lambda i: i%2 == 0, l)
>>> f
<filter object at 0x0000....>
```

Comment: Could you add a small reproducible example to get help quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using Spark in your code.

In case you want a list instead of an RDD :

```
>>> l = range(1,100)  # range object
>>> f = filter(lambda i: i%2 == 0, l)  # filter object
>>> result = list(f)
>>> type(result)
<type 'list'>
>>> result
[2, 4, 6, ...]
```

In case you want an RDD, start with an RDD object :

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize(range(1,100))
>>> rdd2 = rdd.filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
>>> type(rdd2)
<class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>
>>> rdd2.collect()
[2, 4, 6, ...]
```